# Objective-C: whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this code that works so that once i press a button the view changes in my storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code work but when i use it again to change back to my original view using:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It does not work and i receive this error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x863ad30> on <UITabBarController: 0x86309b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

The identifies are set and i am not the functions in my `viewdidload` so i do not know how to fix this.

Can anybody help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24061440/884674

Answer (score 19):

Try this,

First Method

```
-(IBAction)signin:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:vc];

}
```

Second method (to return back to the previous view)

```
- (IBAction)signout:(id)sender
{

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"parentViewController"];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:vc];

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This might happen if you call the method before calling `makeKeyAndVisible`, so move the calling after that.

If not try the hack below:

```
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says all: you have to add the view controller's view to the window before presenting the view controller:

```
UIWindow* keyWindow= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[keyWindow addSubview: viewController.view];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Your code presents the viewconntroller but i still get the same error

Comment: If you look at the documentation for -presentViewController, you'll see that it is supposed to add the controller's view to the hierarchy.