# Whose view is not in the window hierarchy issue?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, hierarchy

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Yes I have looked at the other questions and answers before posting this question. They have not helped me resolve this. Here's what I am doing. I am calling on my singleton class socialHelper to display an action sheet, where `postToFacebook` method is an option to select. When clicking on this action, I get the Warning above and the `postToFacebook` is not displayed. I'm calling this from a UIViewController with the `UINavigationController` as the main controller, and my SocialHelper class is a `NSOject`.

```
- (void)postToFacebook
{
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [slComposeViewController setInitialText:@"Building stairs? Checkout StairsPro on the app store!"];
    [slComposeViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StairsIcon120x120.png"]];
    [slComposeViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stairs-pro/id477032819?ls=1&mt=8"]];

    [self presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    // I've also tried this, which shows the post window, but after hitting cancel or post, my previous viewController is not the current viewController. So my navigation bar is gone and can't move around in my app. 
    // [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]setRootViewController:slComposeViewController];

    }else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Facebook Account" message:@"No Facebook account has been configured. You can configure or create a Facebook account in settings." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
}
}
```

So what I'm asking is what is the best way to get the `slComposerViewController` to display in this case, also how we could use the `UIApplication` option as well. Thank you!

Comment: Is `SocialHelper` actually on screen?

Comment: Nothing is showing on the screen when it's called as far as the PostToFacebook window. Just the Screen I called it from. But the UActionSheet works, then I hit Post to Facebook, and I get the warning and the UIActionSheet goes away, and just back to the screen I called it from.

Comment: `presentViewController:animated:completion:` needs to be called from the viewController that is currently presented on screen. If `SocialHelper` is not the currently presented viewController then you should not be calling this method on it

Comment: I tried moving everything to the UIViewController class thats being displayed and got the same warning.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right viewController?

Comment: No not exactly, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong...just don't know what. Works fine on Cocos2d with CCDirector. Post to facebook is getting called from my aboutView viewController with `[[SocialHelper sharedInstance]shareActionSheet];` which works and shows the action sheet...but once hitting postToFacebook I get the warning. Any ideas? I am using Storyboards for the aboutView if that matters.

Comment: please, share your project; probably the view hierarchy can be messy but without seeing how the view hierarchy is built up, it is very hard even to guess where the problem could be...

Comment: The UINavigationController is the presenting view. I ran a NSLog to see what the current viewController was.

Comment: You need to breakup the problem. I had once issue like this, took whole day to figure out that I was missing 'super' call. 

Try presenting simple view controller
[self presentViewController:[UIViewController new] animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: If you are calling on your singleton class socialHelper to display an action sheet and your SocialHelper class is a NSOject then you don't want (or can't) to use self to display the action sheet because self is an object that's not in the view hierarchy. You need to use a view controller to display the action sheet.

Comment: Here is what I have...MainViewController with a UINavigationController, its a FlipsideViewController for settings, then button for "about" page which is also a UIViewController. I added the log in the about where the UIActionSheet is being called from (Shows UINavigation is the current ViewController). The method for the UIActionSheet is in the socialhelper class which is NSObject. I've Tried moving everything to the About UIViewController class...which gave the same result. Hope this helps

Answer (score 12):

I would change the method to pass in the ViewController to make sure the correct VC is presenting it like so:

```
- (void)postToFacebookFromVC:(UIViewController*) presentingVC
```

And inside that method when calling presentViewController use:

```
[presentingVC presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I assume then that using your socialHelper singleton class would be something like:

```
[[socialHelper sharedResource] postToFacebookFromVC:self]; //inside the VC that you want to display it
```

For your second question on using the rootViewController try this:

```
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Edit: Since the first two suggestions didn't work for your project, try getting the topMost ViewController and presenting slComposeViewController from it instead of "self" like so:

```
UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

while (topController.presentedViewController) {
    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
}

[topController presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: The UINavigationController is the presenting view. I ran a NSLog to see what the current viewController was. Tried both options in current answer, neither worked.

Comment: Here is what I have...MainViewController with a UINavigationController, its a FlipsideViewController for settings, then button for "about" page which is also a UIViewController. I added the log in the about where the UIActionSheet is being called from (Shows UINavigation is the current ViewController). The method for the UIActionSheet is in the socialhelper class which is NSObject. I've Tried moving everything to the About UIViewController class...which gave the same result. Hope this helps

Comment: tried your topViewController, didn't do anything. No errors or crashes, just nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This answer won't resolve your issue but it should make some sense of why it isn't working and help you towards finding the right solution for what you originally intended.

`SLComposeViewController` being a `UIViewController` has an associated `UIView` that will be displayed on top of the view of the controller receiving the message `presentViewController`.

As correctly done in this line but, `self` needs to be a `UIViewController` (an object that has a view property).

```
[self presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It will work if you move your `-postToFaceBook` method out of the `SocialHelper` class and put it inside your `UIViewController` class (file) that will display the action sheet, so that way `self` is actually a `UIViewController` instead of `NSObject`.

From Apple's  [UIViewController reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a):

> When you call the presentViewController method on a UIViewController
>   it sets the presentedViewController property to the specified view
>   controller,  resizes that view controller’s view and then  adds the
>   view to the view hierarchy.

Your `SocialHelper` class is not a view controller so it does not have a view to which the action sheet view could be added to display it (on top).

I'm thinking even if you inherit your `SocialHelper` from `UIViewController`, the view of your `SocialHelper` would not be in your controller's view hierarchy.

If it is only two or three view controllers where you need to display the action sheet, I would replicate the code instead of creating a separate class; if it is several view controllers, then it makes sense to have the action sheet display logic as a separate class, you just need to find the right design pattern to do that.

**Edit 1**

Forgot to mention the declaration of your variable is missing the `SLComposeViewController *`

Is it just missing in your post or you have declared the variable somewhere else in your viewcontroller class?

Try declaring it right there in the same line you create the `SLComposeViewController`; that might fix the issue. If that did not work then double-check all you need to do to support Facebook in your app by looking at this very [simple and easy to follow tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/).

```
SLComposeViewController *slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
```

I'm assuming you created your navigation controller with main view controller as its root:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
```

And to show the flip side controller you do this in your main view controller:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:flipSideViewController animated:NO];
```

The flip side controller has the about button to show the about view when tapped; I'm thinking you do a presentViewController not a push:

```
[self presentViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES];
```

Finally, in the about view controller you should have your -postToFacebook method with the corrected line mentioned above; which will be called by the log (button?).

Comment: Here is what I have...MainViewController with a UINavigationController, its a FlipsideViewController for settings, then button for "about" page which is also a UIViewController. I added the log in the about where the UIActionSheet is being called from (Shows UINavigation is the current ViewController). The method for the UIActionSheet is in the socialhelper class which is NSObject. I've Tried moving everything to the About UIViewController class...which gave the same result. Hope this helps